# Why do different animals have different body temperatures?

Tags: temperature

Why do different animals have different body temperatures.  For example, humans have 37°C, while dogs have 39°C.

Presumably we have ancestors whose temperature differs from ours.  Why would it change over time?

Comment: Because certain species adapt to different conditions by lowering and increasing temperature. Thanks, accept my answer if it helps.

Comment: You get pestered by different microbes at each temperature too